# How to make dragging detection more robust

Tags: jquery, mouseup

I'm storing a global "clicked" status in a variable in order to detect dragging, or to detect if the mouse is being held down while mousing into an element.

The problem is that various things can cause the "clicked" status to remain `true` even when the mouse button is release, for example if an alert pops up.

Is there a solution?

### Edit:

I'm coming to think that "various things" may be limited to alerts, and the browser losing focus due to something like a keyboard shortcut being pressed. I suppose this can be lived with.

Comment: @Acorn: Have you looked at jQueryUI draggable (http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable)?

Comment: I don't actually want to drag things, I want certain elements to change both when they are clicked on, and when they are dragged over (ie. moused over with the mouse button held down). To do that I am having to keep track of the status of the mouse button.

Comment: Is there maybe a way to tell from a `mouseenter` event whether the left mouse button is being held down?

Comment: Not sure. Are you making sure to bind an opposing `mouseup` event handler that sets the "clicked" status appropriately?

Comment: Yep, the only time it breaks is when an alert appears while the user is holding the mouse button down. I suppose I'll just have to make sure not to use alerts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right! the click status cannot be trusted...
it frustrated me for hours.

but maybe JQuery draggable is still a solution for you.

All you need to do is use a transparent helper:

```
$("#draggable3").draggable({
        cursor: "move",
        helper: function( event ) {
            return $( "<div>" );
        },
                     start: function(event, ui){},
                     drag: function(event, ui){},
                     stop: function(event, ui){}
    });
```

more at: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#event-start (the custom helper example)
As a side-kick you can use droppable with hover class:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#visual-feedback

Comment: Hmm, sounds interesting. I wonder what other method jqueryui could be using to keep track of mouse down status? I'm having trouble understanding how your suggestion would be implemented. How would you use jqueryui in this case for example? http://jsfiddle.net/8Uvd7/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NS3Z3/3/
i guess they nailed the clicking thing. it's possible to investigate what they did but i'm sure you'll find a lot of browser switches (if ie, if ff, etc..). with the draggable approach you get the browser support built in and future updates of course of jquery UI.